# RegularExpressionValidator asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, reg-expressionvalidator

I am trying to make sure that user only can input `a-z` and `0-9` characters. 
To do this I have used the RegularExpressionValidator class:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="input" Text="search" runat="server" OnTextChanged="searchFunc"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExp" runat="server"      
                                    ErrorMessage="only a-z or 0-9 allowed" 
                                    ControlToValidate="input"         
                                    ValidationExpression="^[a-z0-9]+$" />
```

Though in the code behind I am trying to check if the user entered valid input by using

```
regExp.IsValid
```

But this method returns True even if user inputs `!&%()`
I can't understand what I've done wrong. Is it my regular expression that is wrong?

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://regex101.com/r/jO7nQ5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call regExp.IsValid only after the validation has been performed otherwise the default value is set to true.

Try calling regExp.Validate() before checking the IsValid property.